# Set font-family for all elements

Tags: css, css-selectors, font-face, font-family

When I have set the font-family for *html, body*..

How can avoid restating the font-family for buttons, input, textarea etc.?

It seems to always default to some other font than my main font-family, on those elements

Setting !important does not help

And as I understand, setting the font-family on * is not advisable

Comment: are you using any CSS frameworks like Bootstrap?

Comment: @ABMagil no, just basic css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could avoid restating by simply setting them all in one go:

```
html,body,buttons,input,textarea,etc {
    font-family: whatever font you want;
}
```

That's probably the simplest way if you're not using *

Comment: Alright, I could live with that.. Do you know which elements are not affected by body font-family? Just wanna target them all ;)

Comment: As far as I know it's form elements:

`button,input,textarea,textfield,select`

There might be a couple of others that I've forgotten, but that's most of them.

Comment: Ah ok, so maybe I could target them all with form * or however you would do that? (that's at least much better than document *)

Comment: Yes, you could target them with form *, but you risk it doing more than it needs to, styling fieldsets, labels and any other text in your forms too. I myself would be more inclined to list the elements, it's cleaner that way. There isn't any downside to it, it's how CSS resets do things after all!